# how to replace more than one character using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace all `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`.

I have used the `.replace()` function but it's not working with `g` or `gi`.

Example here - `http://jsfiddle.net/krishnaTORQUE/RSxnZ/1/`

Comment: show us what you tried to do

Comment: Two replaces? :-) If at first you don't succeed, try again!

Comment: Show us your code. While I've provided an answer, that works (in the context of the posted demo), it's impossible for us to explain the problems with your own attempts until we see those attempts. And while that's not the question you've explicitly *asked*, I think it's the question we should try and answer (*as well as* providing a working solution, obviously). But without the context of your own attempts, we don't know what *else* is, or may be, going wrong.

Comment: I have add a link, please see and let me know how to do that. thank you

Comment: When you tried to add your link, a message appeared, telling you to include code and *not* just post a link to JS Fiddle. Please add your relevant, minimal/[sscce](http://sscce.org/), code to the question. Stack Overflow should still be useful in the absence of other sites.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
var str = '< and >',
    encoded = str.replace(/<|>/g, function(a){
                  return a == '<' ? '&lt;' : '&gt;';
              });
console.log(encoded);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vkSDm/).

As to *why* your own attempt isn't working, it's impossible to say until we can see your attempts.

In view of the posted *link* (please note that showing your code in your question is far more useful), I'd suggest:

```
function disp()
{    
    var text = document.getElementById('textarea').value,
        output = document.getElementById('ibox');
    ibox.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
        text.replace(/<|>/g, function(a){
            return a == '<' ? '&lt;' : '&gt;';
        })
    ));
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RSxnZ/3/), code tested *only* in Chromium 28, on Ubuntu 12.10.

And updated, slightly, to use unobtrusive JavaScript (moving away from inline event-handlers):

```
function disp()
{    
    var text = document.getElementById('textarea').value,
        output = document.getElementById('ibox');
    ibox.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
        text.replace(/<|>/g, function(a){
            return a == '<' ? '&lt;' : '&gt;';
        })
    ));
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    button;
console.log(inputs);

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type == 'button' && inputs[i].value == 'click') {
        button = inputs[i];
    }
}

button.addEventListener('click', disp);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RSxnZ/4/)

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
text = text.replace(/</g, "&lt").replace(/>/g, "&gt");
```

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi - yes, it matched ;) that's the most obvious way. I've deleted my answer to avoid duplication. And I was 10sec faster :P

Comment: @krishnaTORQUE:- Could you share your code which you have tried and which did not worked for you?? As I think this will work fine!!

Answer (score 0):

With a single regex, and a function:

```
var str = '< and >',
var encoded = str.replace(/(<)|(>)/g, 
              function(match, p1, p2) 
              { 
                  if (p1) return '&lt;'; 
                  else return '&gt;'; // equivalent to else (p2)
              })
```

Note the use of `p1` and `p2` that will contain the parenthesized submatch 1 `(<)` and 2 `(>)`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace